# Discontinuous, riemann-integrable function

Tags: calculus

What is an elementary example of a uncontinuous but riemann-integrable function that possesses an explicit antiderivative?

Comment: What is **uncontinuous** ? I heard this term first time...

Comment: Not a word, but presumably **discontinuous** was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the antiderivative, e.g. $$F(x) = \cases{x^2 \sin(1/x) & if $x \ne 0$\cr 0 & if $x = 0$\cr}$$  Its derivative is 
$$ f(x) = \cases{ 2 x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x) & if $x \ne 0$\cr
0 & if $x = 0$\cr}$$